# How can I Install phpMyAdmin on a Nginx?

Tags: software-installation, web-development, lemp, nginx

I have installed `Nginx` on Freya, But i don't know how to install phpMyAdmin on a `LEMP` server.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install phpMyAdmin from `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then you need to create a symbolic link between phpMyAdmin and your site’s directory.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/public_html
```

or

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/nginx/www
```

Then you need to restart your Nginx service

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

First update your system local packages and then install phpMyAdmin from package manager.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Now create a symbolic link from the installation files to our Nginx document root directory by typing.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Now enable the mcrypt PHP module, which phpMyAdmin relies on.

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Then restart your Ngnix service.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: I do not believe you have needed to manually enable mcrypt like this for some time, installing the `php5-mcrypt` package works for me.